# City Name on a Postmark

Tags: place-names

Can someone help me decipher the name of the post office (city name) on postmarks from 1953. I'm not sure if it's Nanking.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is very vague, but looks like 满洲里 to  me:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manzhouli

Comment: The Latin characters "MANCH..." also support this answer.